# Doctrine2 two owning sides

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two models:

Thread <-OneToMany-> Post

Is there a way I can make both sides "owning"? If not, what would be the preferred way of doing this?

Basically, I want this scenario:

```
// When called:
$post->setThread($thread);
$documentManager->persist($post);

// This gets called too, implicitly
$thread->addPost($post);
$documentManager->persist($thread);


// But also, when I call
$thread->addPost($post);
$documentManager->persist($thread);

// This gets called implicitly
$post->setThread($thread);
$documentManager->persist($post);



// When I remove post from thread
$thread->removePost($post);
$documentManager->persist($thread);

// This gets called implicitly
$post->setThread(null);
$documentManager->persist($post);

Etc.
```

So as you can see, I need two-way synchronization with persistence and update cascading.

I could specify this behavior in models themselves to keep them synchronized, but there is a problem with it: Doctrine won't automatically save owning entity if other side was the edited one.

I'm using Doctrine Mongo ODM, but I guess it shouldn't make much of a difference to ORM?

Answer (score 0):

The preferend way would be to set Post to the owning side. In semantics this would be a bit weird because a Thread owns a Post. But in database world Post owns a foreign key to Thread, therefor Post is the owning side and thread the inverse side. For more info read here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Your problem "Doctrine won't automatically save owning entity if other side was the edited one." is also documentated there as "Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.". So you just have to be consistent about it and always update the owning side of the relationship. It's a good idea to update the inverse side inside the owning side method to keep things in sync. That is .. in sync for your objects in PHP, the database will only need to know about the owning side anyway...